# how to fix the red class to green can be pushed on github

Tags: android, android-studio, github, push

how to fix the red class to green can be pushed on github, every time I go to github, I don't go to push because it's still red, after editing it's usually green

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If files are `Red` means files are not added to Git.To Add files to git follow below steps

> Steps for Add files to git:

Select File which is need to add,next write click on file -> Git->Add

Please refer below screenshot for adding files to git:-

[image]

After follow these steps now you can commit and push the files to git.

> Steps for Commit files:

Click on VCS->Commit

Refer below screenshot for Commit:-

[image]

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

The below file is red because its not added to your git repository.

[image]

for adding and committing it to the git repository you must **add**->**commit**->**push**.
There are multiple ways to do so, one way is using the Gui controls available in the android Studio or using the Command line commands.

Below screenshot shows how it is done in android studio.

[image]

You can Commit and Push the files whichever you want to be updated in the repository.

Commands to update your new files into repository are :

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
//resolve your conflicts
git add <filename>
git commit -m "<commit message>"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

it because you just create a new file and not insert into the commit file, if you binding your git into android studio select **VCS -> GIT -> Commit File**.

Then on the dialog make sure you have already a checkmark on the file still red, then you can commit the file, after you  do that, that will become green when you have changes on your file.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
right clicked the file -> GIT -> Add.

Comment: There's really no need for you to add this answer. The accepted answer shows exactly this already.